# Upload zip to checkmarx server is not working from teamcity checkmarx scan pipepline

Tags: teamcity, checkmarx

We had configured a pipeline in TeamCity, including the Checkmarx runner and all the necessary parameters. Initially, everything was functioning properly. However, when we attempt to run the pipeline now, we encounter a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error.

I have attached the screenshot of the error

[image]

During our investigation, we discovered that the zip file is not being successfully uploaded to the Checkmarx server.

However, when we attempt to use a different repository URL in the VCS root, it functions correctly according to our expectations.

How do we fix this?